# How to execute the other schema stored procedures?

Tags: java, mysql

I am working in a java web application project. I have the requirement like, i want to invoke the other schema stored procedure to execute in some other schema.

But, when i am trying this approach, it's showing `error like the table already exists(contains in SP).` I can understand what the issue is, it's calling the stored procedure in same schema itself where the stored procedure was created.

Following is the detailed illustration

```
 1. Schema1(Subscription) - Stored procedure created is here
 2. Schema2(Subscription1)- Executing the stored procedure here like following

    > USE Subscription1;  
    > CALL subscription.createcorporatedbproc();
```

Please help me to know about this issue.

Comment: Might possible be your procedure is creating table which already exist there can you post procedure here ?

Comment: There is no table in that schema. I am executing stored procedure to create the table does not exists.....here is the stored procedure        DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `createCorporateDBProc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createCorporateDBProc`()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE `xxxx`
  (
    `ORDER_ORDER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `INFO_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `OFFER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
  )
  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your SP you can create it in one schema and call it from there, you just need to pass database name as parameter in which you need to create the table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createCorporateDBProc`(IN DBName CHAR(100))
BEGIN 

     SET @DBName = DBName;
     SET @varSQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',@DBName,'.xxxx( ORDER_ORDER_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, INFO_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, OFFER_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL )  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;' );
     PREPARE stmt FROM @varSQL;
     EXECUTE stmt ;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

     /** If you need to create more tables , Replicate these 4 lines with your table structure **/
     SET @varSQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',@DBName,'.yyyy( ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, InfoID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, TagID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL )  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;' );
     PREPARE stmt FROM @varSQL;
     EXECUTE stmt ;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Testing CALL statement , I will create a new database and then i will call SP it to create the table in it.

```
mysql> create database mydb_test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL createCorporateDBProc('mydb_test');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

mysql> show tables from mydb_test;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_mydb_test |
+---------------------+
| xxxx                |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE on 26 Jan,2014**

Create a sample database and create all tables which you need in that sample database, and then you can use this sample database to create other databases

Comment: Mr.Abdul, actually i am executing this stored procedure in other schema. I want to execute this stored procedure in other schema not in same schema. Can you get me?

Comment: You need to create this table in other schemas ?

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.Abdul.Yeah...Now, it's working for me to create the single table. . But, i want to execute more tables using this procedure. For example, i want to execute 1000 tables. Can you help me to know about this?

Comment: But, i think this is not a good approach. It will take lot of time to create 1000 more tables. Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Obviously this is not a good approach. Updated my answer you can use that approach

Comment: I need to use only stored procedure approach to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Let's assume like i have the sample database that has all tables. So, in this case,how can i call that tables to other database using stored procedure approach.Mr.Abdul, Can you give me sample query?

Comment: Instead of creating SP create a script(that will contain all SQL Statements i.e CREATE TABLE's) and execute it while needed.

Comment: So, you are telling me to encapsulate all tables in one single SQL script file.Already, i tried that approach but my requirement is i should use only SP. So, is there any possibilities to achieve this in SP?